# What does (social function) mean in that sentence?

Tags: meaning

what is the (social function) mean in this sentence?
(He never goes to any social function unless his wife can come with him.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means any public gathering, like a party or the opening of a new art gallery, or school graduation, etc.  A "social function" is one where people mingle and chat with each other; rarely is anything of importance the subject, but if it is, the important item is typically mentioned only in a brief reference, in passing. The conversation is usually "small talk".